# How to pass two PK through urls in Django?

Tags: python, django

I've created a function that adds the user to an event, that is working fine but, i'm having problems with the one that removes the users from the event, I didn`t figure out how to get the attendant so that the owner can remove it.

By now, I have this:

views.py (Function that adds the user to the event)

```
@login_required
def request_event(request, pk):
    previous = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
    try:
        post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
        Attending.objects.create(post=post, attendant=request.user)
        messages.success(request, f'Request sent!')
        return redirect(previous)
    except post.DoesNotExist:
        return redirect('/')
```

(Function that **removes users from the event, handled by the event owner**)

```
@login_required
def remove_attendant(request, pk, id):
    previous = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
    try:
        post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
        attendant = Attending.objects.get(id=attendance_id)
        Attending.objects.filter(post=post, attendant=attendant).delete()
        messages.success(request, f'User removed!')
        return redirect(previous)
    except post.DoesNotExist:
        return redirect('/')
```

Urls.py

```
path('post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/remove_attendant/(?P<attendance_id>[0-9]+)$', views.remove_attendant, name='remove-attendant'),
```

Any help or comment will be very welcome! thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

`attendance_id` seems to be undefined in your code.

`def remove_attendant(request, pk, attendance_id):` should be what you're calling.

Also in theory, you should be able to access both `pk` and `attendance_id` from `request.resolver_match.kwargs` anyways.

Comment: Tried that but didnt work... Is giving me a 404 error... The link is actually getting the post PK twice, instead of getting the post PK and the attendance_id

Comment: @chrislumber well `attendance_id` was undefined and `id` unused, that's for sure because I checked syntax highlight for that. As for 404, are you sure `request.resolver_match.kwargs.get("attendance_id", None)` is not giving you a valid int?

Comment: do you mean like this? Attending.objects.filter(post=post, attendant=request.resolver_match.kwargs.get("attendance_id", None)).delete() or #attendant = request.resolver_match.kwargs.get("attendance_id", None) ? The two ways are giving a 404... might be the url?

Comment: @chrislumber then the routing does not match whatever URL you're trying to get, yes. If none of the routing patterns are matching for what you want to visit, Django returns a 404. Try this: since it's a regex, and you use `$` at the end of the pattern, also add a `^` to the beginning. Maybe your regex is broken

Comment: Still giving me a 404...
path('^post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/remove_attendant/(?P<attendance_id>[0-9]+)$', views.remove_attendant, name='remove-attendant'),

and in the html: href="/post/{{ object.pk }}/remove_attendant/{{ object.attendance_id }}"

Comment: @chrislumber I'm out of ideas then. There must be some other error in some other parts of your code. Passing variables to the render context might be a good start. And also readng more of the Django docs, because you have no `object` in your template unless you explicitly passed such key, or you use `DetailView` class, which you don't.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use positional arguments in your url path, no need for regex.  Your variable names can also be descriptive, if it helps (if often helps me).

```
path('remove-attendant-view/<post_id>/<attendance_id>/', views.remove_attendant, name='remove_attendant'),
```

And in views.py, something like:

```
def remove_attendant(request, post_id, attendance_id):
```

And whereever you call this view function, you must ensure your url has those ids and pks in context and in order, for example something like:

```
<a href="{% url 'remove_attendant' post_id=post_id, attendant_id=attendance_id %}">Remove Attendant</a>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is giving me this error: "Reverse for 'remove-attendant' with keyword arguments '{'post_id': '', 'attendant_id': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['es/remove\\-attendant\\-view/(?P<post_id>[^/]+)/(?P<attendant_id>[^/]+)/\\Z']"

Comment: You're welcome!  Ah, the good ole' reverse not found error.  This is likely because your template where you have added the `{% url %}` does not have the two ids in its context.  Make sure that the view that creates that template is getting and passing that context.

Comment: Yes! tried that but didn't work :(

Comment: You should add the view code that creates the page where you call the remove_attendant url function.  That might help troubleshoot.